# How do I FILTER returned data between two dates from mongodb using an aggregation : match, lookup and project?

Tags: mongodb, filtering, lookup, aggregation, projection

I would like to get all Notifications between a start and end date that are related to a Register when I pass in a userId.

### Register Schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const RegisterSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    accessToken: {type:String, required: true, default: null},
})
module.exports = Register = mongoose.model( 'register', RegisterSchema)
```

Here is some register data

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "5eac9e815fc57b07f5d0d29f",
    "userId": "5ea108babb65b800172b11be",
    "accessToken": "111"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ecaeba3c7b910d3276df839",
    "userId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b",
    "accessToken": "222"
  }
]
```

The next document contains data that is related to the Register schema via the accessToken

### Notifications

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    accessToken: {type:String, required: true},
    summaryId: {type:Number, required: true},
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})
module.exports = Notification = mongoose.model( 'notification', NotificationSchema)
```

Here is some notification data

```js
[{
    "_id": "5ebf0390c719e60004f42e74",
    "accessToken": "111",
    "summaryId": 1111,
    "dateCreated": "17 Apr 2020" }, 
  {
    "_id": "6ebf0390c719e60004f42e76",
    "accessToken": "222",
    "summaryId": 2221,
    "dateCreated": "18 Apr 2020" },
  {
    "_id": "6ebf0390c719e60004f42e78",
    "accessToken": "111",
    "summaryId": 1112,
    "dateCreated": "25 May 2020" },
  {
    "_id": "6ebf0390c719e60004f42e80",
    "accessToken": "222",
    "summaryId": 2222,
    "dateCreated": "26 May 2020" }
]
```

### Try 1

```js
        var userId = '5ea108babb65b800172b11be'
        var dateStart = '27 Apr 2020';
        var dateEnd   = '27 May 2020'; 

        var match = {$match: { userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } };

        var lookup ={
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "notifications",
                localField: "accessToken",
                foreignField: "accessToken",
                as: "testingThis"
            }
        };

        project = {
            $project: {
                items: {
                    $filter: {
                    input: "$items",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: { {"dateCreated": {'$gte': dateStart, '$lte': dateEnd }} }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var agg = [
            match,
            lookup,
            project
        ];


        Register.aggregate(agg)
        .then( events => {
            if(events){
                return resolve(events);
            }else{
                return reject({success:false});
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('ERROR ' + JSON.stringify(err.message));
            return reject({success:false});
        })
```

### Try 1 Error

I am expecting to see the notification for 25 May for accessToken of 111, but I am getting an error:

```js
ERROR : {"\"An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: new Date(1588017802546), $lte: new Date(1590609802546) }\""}
```

### Try 2

I got rid of the error ... but still getting nothing returned:

```js
        var dateCondition = { $and: [
            { $gte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateStart.getTime() ] },
            { $lte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateEnd.getTime() ] }
          ] }

          project = {
            $project: {
                items: {
                    $filter: {
                    input: "$items",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: dateCondition
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

This is what my project looks like:

```js
{
  "$project": {
    "items": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$items",
        "as": "item",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            {"$gte": ["$$item.dateCreated",1588019227296] },
            {"$lte": ["$$item.dateCreated",1590611227296] }
          ] } } } }
}
```

### Try 3

using advice from comments... I changed 'items' (from try 2) to 'notifications'

```js
        var dateCondition = { $and: [
            { $gte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateStart.getTime() ] },
            { $lte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateEnd.getTime() ] }
          ] }

          project = {
            $project: {
                notifications: {
                    $filter: {
                    input: "$notifications",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: dateCondition
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

still does not work

so in an attempt to simplify as much as I can to get this to work... I am trying it with summary id

### Try 4

```js
          dateCondition = { $and: [
            { $gte: [ "$$item.summaryId", 1 ] },
            { $lte: [ "$$item.summaryId", 555555 ] }
          ] }          

          project = {
            $project: {
                notifications: {
                    $filter: {
                    input: "$notifications",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: dateCondition
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

which works... so that leads me to think it is a date problem.

### Final Code - works!

```js
        // make sure the input dates are REALLY date objects
        var dateStart = new Date(inputDateStart);
        var dateEnd = new Date(inputDateEnd);     

        var match = {$match: { userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } };

        var lookup ={
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "my_Notifications",
                localField: "accessToken",
                foreignField: "accessToken",
                as: "notifications"
            }
        };

        var dateCondition = { $and: [
            { $gte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateStart ] },
            { $lte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateEnd ] }
          ]}  

        project = {
            $project: {
                notifications: {
                    $filter: {
                    input: "$notifications",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: dateCondition
                    } } }
        };

        var agg = [
            match,
            lookup,
            project
        ];

        Register.aggregate(agg)
        .then( ..... )
```

Comment: 1. Please provide your expected output. 2. Are you sure the `dateCreated ` is stored as `Date` ? It's defined in the schema as date but your output in the database looks like a `String`

Comment: I put the date as a string in the example for clarity... it is a date in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks almost right, provided that `dateStart` and `dateStart` are actually `Date` objects and not `String`s.

Your **Try 2** was incomplete I'm not sure it uses the `$lookup` from **Try 1** or not. If so you have to make sure the output of `$lookup` is the same as input of `$filter`. So you should change `as` in `$lookup` to match `input` of `$filter`

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "notifications",
    localField: "accessToken",
    foreignField: "accessToken",
    as: "items" // here
  }

}
```

**Alternative Solution**

I'm not sure what you want as output. If you only need array of notifications without the user object, you can try the following.

```
[{
  $match: { userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: "notifications",
    localField: "accessToken", // don't forget to index register.accessToken
    foreignField: "accessToken", // don't forget to index notification.accessToken
    as: "notifications"
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$notifications"
}, {
  $match: { 
    dateCreated: { $gte: dateStart, $lte: dateEnd } // dateStart, dateEnd should be Date objects
  }
}, { // optional, move notifications to top lvel
  $replaceRoot: { root: '$notifications' }
}]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1656749/thammada - thank you so much !  That helped out