# How do I SORT only the fields ($project) returned from Mongodb aggregation, while also using $match, $lookup AND $filter

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pipeline, aggregation, projection

I am VERY close to getting what I want out of this query... but now I want to ***sort on a notification field***

**NOTE**: This is a refinement : I am now asking how to return ***SORT on notification fields***, while my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026641/how-do-i-filter-returned-data-between-two-dates-from-mongodb-using-an-aggregatio/62053768#62053768) asks how to return the data ***between a start and end date*** and my other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066169/how-do-i-only-return-some-fields-project-from-mongodb-aggregation-while-also/62067912?noredirect=1#comment109831764_62067912) asks how to return ***only certain fields***.

### Register Schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const RegisterSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    accessToken: {type:String, required: true, default: null},
})
module.exports = Register = mongoose.model( 'register', RegisterSchema)
```

Here is some register data

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "Reg_1",
    "userId": "User_1",
    "accessToken": "a_1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "Reg_2",
    "userId": "User_2",
    "accessToken": "a_2"
  }
]
```

The next document contains data that is related to the Register schema via the accessToken

### Notifications

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    accessToken: {type:String, required: true},
    summaryId: {type:Number, required: true},
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},

    // I don't want these returned in the final results
    dontWantThis1: {type:Number, required: true},
    dontWantThis2: {type:Number, required: true},
})
module.exports = Notification = mongoose.model( 'notification', NotificationSchema)
```

Here is some notification data

```js
[{
    "_id": "N1_1",
    "accessToken": "a_1",
    "summaryId": 1111,
    "dontWantThis1": 61,
    "dontWantThis2": 62,
    "dateCreated": "2020-04-17T00:00:00.000+00:00" }, 
  {
    "_id": "N2_1",
    "accessToken": "a_2",
    "summaryId": 2221,
    "dontWantThis1": 71,
    "dontWantThis2": 72,
    "dateCreated": "2020-04-18T00:00:00.000+00:00" },
  {
    "_id": "N1_2",
    "accessToken": "a_1",
    "summaryId": 1112,
    "dontWantThis1": 611,
    "dontWantThis2": 622,
    "dateCreated": "2020-05-25T00:00:00.000+00:00" },
  {
    "_id": "N2_2",
    "accessToken": "a_2",
    "summaryId": 2222,
    "dontWantThis1": 711,
    "dontWantThis2": 722,
    "dateCreated": "2020-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00" }
]
```

### Starting with this

This code returns everything I want... but doesn't **sort** the notifications by dateCreated showing the newest dates first.

```js
        // make sure the input dates are REALLY date objects
        // I only want to see notifications for the month of May (in this example)
        var dateStart = new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00');
        var dateEnd = new Date('2020-05-30T00:00:00.000+00:00');     

        var match = {$match: { userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } };

        var lookup ={
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "my_Notifications",
                localField: "accessToken",
                foreignField: "accessToken",
                as: "notifications"
            }
        };

        var dateCondition = { $and: [
            { $gte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateStart ] },
            { $lte: [ "$$item.dateCreated", dateEnd ] }
          ]}  

        var project = {
            $project: {
                notifications: {
                    $filter: {
                    input: "$notifications",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: dateCondition
                    } } }
        };


        var project2 = {
            $project: {
                "_id": 1,
                "userId": 1,
                "accessToken":1,
                "count":{$size:"$notifications"},
                "notifications._id":1,
                "notifications.summaryId": 1,
                "notifications.dateCreated":1,
                "notifications.dateProcessed":1,
            }
        };


        var agg = [
            match,
            lookup,
            project,
            project2,
        ];


        Register.aggregate(agg)
        .then( ..... )
```

### Expected Results

I would like to have the notifications sorted by latest date to earliest date

**NOTE**: It doesn't matter which "accessToken" is the first record... just that the dates of the notifications *in EACH accessToken record* are latest to earliest AND all of the data is present :

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "Reg_1",
    "accessToken": "a_1",
    "userId": "User_1",
    "count": 2,
    "notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "N1_2",
        "dateCreated": ISODate("2020-05-25T00:00:00Z"),
        "summaryId": 1112
      },
      {
        "_id": "N1_1",
        "dateCreated": ISODate("2020-04-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "summaryId": 1111
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Reg_2",
    "accessToken": "a_2",
    "userId": "User_2",
    "count": 2,
    "notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "N2_2",
        "dateCreated": ISODate("2020-05-26T00:00:00Z"),
        "summaryId": 2222
      },
      {
        "_id": "N2_1",
        "dateCreated": ISODate("2020-04-18T00:00:00Z"),
        "summaryId": 2221
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

previous tries removed for brevity

### Try 6

I am getting closer with this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GkSiWHbh1E4) attempt, but

#### Try 6 close... but no cigar

I am getting this... instead of the expected results

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "accessToken": "a_2",
      "userId": "User_2"
    },
    "notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "N2_2",
        "dateCreated": "2020-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "summaryId": 2222
      },
      {
        "_id": "N2_1",
        "dateCreated": "2020-04-18T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "summaryId": 2221
      }
    ],
    "notifications_count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "accessToken": "a_1",
      "userId": "User_1"
    },
    "notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "N1_2",
        "dateCreated": "2020-05-25T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "summaryId": 1112
      },
      {
        "_id": "N1_1",
        "dateCreated": "2020-04-17T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "summaryId": 1111
      }
    ],
    "notifications_count": 2
  }
]
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

OK.. after much playing around in mongodb and a dozen google searches.

Here is the answer to make the output the same as the expected results

```js
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "accessToken": {
        "$first": "$accessToken"
      },
      "userId": {
        "$first": "$userId"
      },
      "n_count": {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "notifications": {
        $push: "$notifications"
      }
    }
  }
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8XaIOW7gKAg

Answer (score -1):

You can use [$lookup , $unwind , $sort , $group] aggregation pipeline stages to sort the content of notification array. [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/auf57Fkc9MX)

```
    db.Register.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "my_Notifications",
          localField: "accessToken",
          foreignField: "accessToken",
          as: "notifications"
        }
      },
      {
       // cartesian product of array lengths
        $unwind: "$notifications"
      },
      {
        $sort: {
         // Sort the records by created date
          "notifications.dateCreated": -1
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          "_id": {
            "accessToken": "$accessToken",
            "userId": "$userId"
          },
          "notifications": {
            $push: "$notifications"
          },
          "notifications_count": {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

Comment: thank you... see Try 6 for question and my latest attempt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/136054/nayakam - I have updated the question to match my mongo playground